# Binary Search Tree using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: binary-search-tree, genetic-algorithm

Does anybody know how to construct a binary search tree using a genetic algorithm and if it's even possible? I wanted to try it as an assignment but I'm not sure where to begin. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you do with that tree, assuming you have it? What would it be optimized for?

Comment: @maxy It would be to optimize the output function so that values are obtained faster.

Comment: Maybe you start with a tree without any constraint on number of leaf nodes per node. Then it should converge into binary tree (fast access = maxima).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.